# Invalid argument using bind() in C

Tags: c, sockets, bind

This is the code that should create the socket and do the binding

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SOCKNAME "./serverSC"

#define RETURNSYSCALL(r, c, e) if((r=c) == -1) {perror(e); exit(errno);}
#define SYSCALL(c, e) if(c == -1) {perror(e); exit(errno);}

void cleanup();

int main()
{
    cleanup();
    atexit(cleanup);

    int socketFd, socketComFd;
    struct sockaddr_un socketName;

    memset(&socketName, '0', sizeof(socketName));
    socketName.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(socketName.sun_path, SOCKNAME, strlen(SOCKNAME)+1);

    RETURNSYSCALL(socketFd, socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0), "Impossibile creare una socket");    
    SYSCALL(bind(socketFd, (struct sockaddr *) &socketName, sizeof(socketFd)), "Impossibile fare la bind");
    SYSCALL(listen(socketFd, 10), "Impossibile fare la listen");
    RETURNSYSCALL(socketComFd, accept(socketFd, NULL, 0), "impossibile fare la accept");

    return 0;
}

void cleanup() {
  unlink(SOCKNAME);
}
```

But the output it prints is:

```
Impossibile fare la bind: Invalid argument
```

some recommend using "AF_INET" instead of "AF_UNIX", but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I like that you actually try to handle errors. You don't "catch" undefined behavior this way though.

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third argument of [`bind()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) is the size of *address*, so it should be `sizeof(socketName)`, not `sizeof(socketFd)`, in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
memset(&socketName, '0', sizeof(socketName));
```

`'0'` makes no sense whatsoever. Use `0` (no quotation marks).

```
strncpy(socketName.sun_path, SOCKNAME, strlen(SOCKNAME)+1);
```

The size parameter of the `strncpy` is meant to be the size of the **destination buffer**, not the source string. The latter is completely and utterly useless. If you want to copy the entire source string, just use `strcpy`, it does exactly that. Moreover, `strncpy` is a dangerous function that should be used with caution. It does not necessarily null-terminate the target buffer, and people tend to forget about that. If you insist, do it this way:

```
strncpy (socketName.sun_path, SOCKNAME, sizeof(socketName.sun_path));
socketName.sun_path[sizeof(socketName.sun_path) - 1] = 0;
```

Finally, `sizeof(socketFd)` should be `sizeof(socketName)`.